# React Router V4, var undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've followed this tutorial here: https://www.kirupa.com/react/creating_single_page_app_react_using_react_router.htm
and built the router no problem in a static HTML build. 
I am now dissecting the code into separate js files for my web application.

I've put the REMDOM in the usual place the index.js as it was orginally, how ever when declaring the var to shorten the prefix it's throwing an undeclared error. 
It worked on the static, so not sure why it's now now. Here's what I got:

```
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import React from 'react-router';
    import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'
    import './index.css'; 
    import App from './App';
    import Routes from './Routes';
    import Contact from './Pages/Contact';
    import Projects from './Pages/Projects';
    import Home from './Pages/Home';


    var destination = document.querySelector("#root");

    var { Router,
    Route,
    IndexRoute,
    IndexLink,
    hashHistory,
    Link } = ReactRouter;

    ReactDOM.render(
     <Router history={hashHistory}>
       <Route path="/" component={Routes}>
         <IndexRoute component={Home} />
         <Route path="projects" component={Projects} />
         <Route path='contact' component={Contact} />
       </Route>
     </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

And my Routes.js file:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    var Routes = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
      return (
    <div>
      <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
      <ul className="header">
        <li><IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</IndexLink></li>
        <li><Link to="products" activeClassName="active">Products</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="contact" activeClassName="active">Contact</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <div className="content">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
     </div>
     )
    }
  });

  export default Routes;
```

However I am getting this error: 
  ./src/index.js
  Line 22:  'ReactRouter' is not defined  no-undef

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: well you have no variable named `ReactRouter`... so yea...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `ReactRouter` somewhere before using it in the destructuring assignment `var { ... } = ReactRouter;`.  Try changing the import statement

```
import React from 'react-router';
```

to

```
import ReactRouter from 'react-router';
```